# Creating an Array of Queues

Tags: java, arrays, class, constructor, queue

I have to make a program in Java that includes an array of queues created from my queue class that I have made which is as follows -

```
class Queue1{  //each line at the supermarket

    public Queue1(int s){                             //constructor
        maxSize = s;
        pplLines = new long[maxSize];
        front = 0;
        rear = -1;
        nItems = 0;
    }

    public void insert(long j){                    //put item at rear of queue
        if(rear == maxSize - 1)                    //deal with wraparound
            rear = -1;
        pplLines[++rear] = j;                      //increment rear and insert
        nItems++;                                  //one more item
    }

    public long remove(){                          //take item from front of queue
        long temp = pplLines[front++];             //get value and increment front
        if(front == maxSize)                       //deal with wraparound
            front = 0;                             
        nItems--;                                  //one less item
        return temp;
    }

    public long peekFront(){                       //peek at front of queue
        return pplLines[front];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){                      //true if queue is empty
        return (nItems == 0);
    }

    public boolean isFull(){                       //true if queue is full
        return (nItems == maxSize);
    }

    public int size(){                             //number of items in queue
        return nItems;
    }


    public void display(){                                         //display contents of queue
        for (int i = 0; i < nItems; i++) {
        System.out.println(pplLines[(front + i) % maxSize]);
    }
    }


        }//ends queue class
```

So how can I reference the queue class into an array starting with this

public SuperMarket(int num_clerks, int line_size){

After that I have the array of queues created I need to find the shortest line to insert a customer where I have to input the number of clerks/lines available at the supermarket, how would I go about adding that to my SuperMarket class?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Add the field `Queue[] queues` to your Supermarket. Also, Java already has a Queue class.

Answer (score 0):

if you do something like

```
public SuperMarket(int num_clerks, int line_size){ 

    List<Queue1> clerks = new ArrayList<Queue1>();
    for(int i; i< num_clerks; i++){
        clerks.add(new Queue1(line_size))
    }
}
```